# Hello world example not working in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have installed React.js using the following command:

```
create-react-app my-app
```

now i open my command line and i execute the following command:

```
npm start
```

The App opens in my browser at the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Now i go to the public/src/app.js folder and change the code from the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Why did you do ?? 
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

To the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export default App;
```

But i get the following error. Why ?

> ```
> Failed to compile
> ./src/App.js
>   Line 5:   'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef
>   Line 10:  'App' is not defined       no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors are pretty self-explanatory:

> Line 5:   'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef

You are using `ReactDOM.render`, but you're not importing it, so it's not defined.

Also, you probably *don't* want to use it at all, because it's already being called in another file (`src/index.js`).

> Line 10:  'App' is not defined       no-undef

The original code declared a class `App` and exported it. You removed the class declaration, but you kept the export, which references the now non-existent class `App`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

and delete `export default App;`

Answer (score 1):

you are not importing React-DOM,
jsut add

`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have describe this example to understand

> For Example: **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';  // Step 1: import ReactDOM 
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// export default App;// Step 2 :- This line is comment
```

I hope **'Hello world'** example is working in **React.js**.